# click() at the top of span button doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to make buttons using the simple structure :

```
<a href="#/category/portfolio/" class="filter" data-filter="*">
<span class="button">Tout</span>
</a>
```

It works, except for the very top of the buttons. We can click on it, the CSS activates, but not the jQuery related.

http://jsfiddle.net/vqrdW/

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @amosrivera - Really? I see the issue in Chrome 16 if you click right at the top (like the top couple of pixels).

Comment: my bad you are right, the problem appears when clicking the top 2 pixels

Comment: I see the problem also, tested in Chrome 16 and Firefox 8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with this rule:

```
.button:active { 
   position: relative; 
   top: 3px;
}
```

As the button moves down by 3 pixels, when the mouse button is released, the cursor is not over the button so the action is not registered. If you comment out this chunk of code you can see that it fixes the problem.

Try instead to come up with a different effect for when the button is pressed that does not move the button to one side or another.

Comment: +1, Well spotted, I was looking for something along those lines but you beat me to it :)

Comment: +1 for that.. I wondered if it had something to do with this rule.

Comment: Agree with James. I was assuming it was related to the shadows. So close. Chrome 16, works fine after removing the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I lost 1 hour searching. I'll ask community next time !

Answer (score 1):

Add the padding on the a tag instead of the .button:

```
a.filter {
  padding: 8px 14px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.span:active {   
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works so there is context to your answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="#/category/portfolio/" class="filter" data-filter="*">
<span class="button" style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%">Tout</span>
</a>
```

not working... sorry...
here is a working version
EDITED:

```
a.filter {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
float:left;
line-height:40px; /*(or whatever is that button's height)*/
}
```

Comment: If you are already setting display block, setting width and height is useless. Also the other buttons do work and use span as well.